# WordPress: Add text after (or before) previously posted content based on publish date

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've been searching for a while now with no certain answer. I'm looking to append text to a WordPress site for prior posts that is moving from one domain to a new one and retaining content.

So what I want to do is, add "This article was originally posted at xyz.com." to all posts that were posted before today's date.

Right now this could be done through the database, or a WP functions filter, I'm okay with either option as long as it is long lasting.

Any suggestions on how to go about this would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `the_content` filter that like this:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'old_wp_content' ); 
function old_wp_content( $content ) { 
  if( get_the_date('Y-m-d') < "2017-02-28" ) {
    $content = "<p>This article was originally posted at xyz.com.</p>" . $content;
  }
  return $content;
}
```

This filter gets fired when you call `the_content()` of a post. with `the_content` filter you can adjust the return value of the `the_content()` function.

Comment: So to make sure I have this correct, I'm replacing "YOUR_DATE" with the date I want it to start from going back?

Comment: It all depends what time format you're trying to compare. But If you compare two of the same time formats, that's how it works indeed. Read more about the `get_the_date()` function here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date

Comment: I have to be missing something here. I tried `if(get_the_date() < 2017-02-28 00:00:01) {` and `if(get_the_date() < 2017-02-28T00:00:01+00:00) {` as a testing point and it is not showing any change to the page(s).

Comment: @jdkrause I've updated my answer to your requirements. You've to format the return value of `get_the_date` to match your data format.

Comment: Thanks for that, now I'm actually getting some kind of reaction from that filter, but unfortunately no single post pages will load.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying this solution both at work and at home. It appears my MAMP decided it no longer wanted to start MySQL. So that is a problem for another day. I have tried your solution here again at work and I was not getting any results.

Comment: And using that in combination with the time check I've written in the answer? I'm not sure why the code you've just posted working, while my shorter version didn't :) But I'm glad you've figured it out.

Comment: Just realized I was missing that part. When I add the `if( if(get_the_date('Y-m-d') < "2017-02-28" ) {` to the filter, I get a 500 Error. Generally that means MAMP doesn't like something in the functions.php file.

Comment: So my hybrid filter solution did NOT work (as noted above). When I use the code @kevinvhengst posted, I get a white page for my posts and the Admin won't load (MAMP throws a 500 error). If I do a varied filter with just a `$beforecontent` and `$aftercontent` to add text to the posts, that works fine. So I'm guessing it has something to do with the date query part of the filter.

Comment: Can you see the apache error logs in MAMB? That should give an indication of why it is going wrong. I've tested my code on my machine and it works fine.

Comment: The error is actually appearing in the PHP log file -- "[21-Apr-2017 18:43:09 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/themes/blog/functions.php on line 240" -- is what it says.

Comment: Very strange. Are you 100% sure you've copied it exactly as the example I've given? I've tested it again and works fine for me :)

Comment: Yeah, I tried it multiple times with the same result. It's possible it was reacting that way due to another filter in the functions file, but when I changed it to the code I posted in my answer below, it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it. That extra "if" before the `get_the_date` statement and possibly the double quotation marks (swapped for single) wrapping the p tags for the inserted text were the culprits. The following code works:

```
function old_wp_content( $content ) {
  if (get_the_date('Y-m-d') < '2017-02-28' ) {
    $content = $content . '<p>This article was originally posted at <a 
rel="canonical" href="#">xyz.com</a>.</p>';
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'old_wp_content' );
```

@kevinvhengst, thanks again for your time and patience in helping me figure this out!